# java enforce singleton in class hierarchy

Tags: java, oop

In Java, Is there a way to enforce the implementations of my interface are singletons? I have interfaces that I want to ensure are implemented by classes with a single instance - is this something I can do with abstract classes?

Edit: more context

I am implementing a framework that defines a platform interface that I need only instance of, per implementation since it is going to be used a lot.

Comment: I don't think so (unless, perhaps, you want a [**Multiton**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) - which is a little more complex then what you *describe*). But at the moment this question exhibits the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/243725). Please tell us **why** you want to do this, and how you intend to use it.

Comment: May not work at all for how you imagine your framwork but: Make it required at construction time, e.g. `new Framework(Platform pf)` then never again request a reference to it. That way there is 1 instance of the platform interface you need to care about.

Answer (score 1):

I can show you a dirty trick there:

```
static public abstract class SingletonAbc {
    static private final HashSet<Class<?>>  mInstancedClasses   = new HashSet<>();

    public SingletonAbc() { // CTOR should be thread-safe imo, check that to be sure
        final Class<?> c = getClass();
        System.out.println("Checking Class: " + c.getName());
        if (mInstancedClasses.contains(c)) throw new IllegalStateException("Damn, cannot instantiate the class " + c.getName() + " twice!");
        else mInstancedClasses.add(c);
    }
}

static public class Ext1 extends SingletonAbc {}
static public class Ext2 extends SingletonAbc {}
static public class Ext1Ext1 extends Ext1 {}
static public class Ext1Ext2 extends Ext1 {}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new Ext1();
    new Ext2();
    new Ext1Ext1();
    new Ext1Ext2();
    new Ext2(); // <= bam! exception!
}
```

But keep in mind that might not be the best solution. Factors like multithreading and reflection might kill this approach.